# Specific Animation: Object Falling Into Snow

Tags: animation, resource-recommendations, template-design

I was wondering if anyone knows where I could find a template for After Effects that involves a ball or some other object being dropped into water, snow, smoke, or some other kind of environment.  Are there websites that might be helpful for this?

Answer (score 1):

Only site I'm familiar with that might be worth looking at is VideoHive.net for example here's the query [Falling In Water](http://videohive.net/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=fall%20in%20water). You'll have to check the license requirements though because they're fairly strict in how many times it can be used after purchasing.